# How to set button and text color in Android Alert Dialog

Tags: android, alert

I am modifying code for an Android app.
The code generates an Alert Dialog, and should present the user with two buttons.
However, when the Alert Dialog is shown, the two buttons / options are not visible.

I read other posts that suggest that the text and background colours are both white.
So the suggestion is to modify the text colour etc.
All the examples I can find suggest something like the following:

```
val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = Builder(this, .style.DialogTheme)
```

where the style is defined like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

However, the code I am trying to modify is formatted differently, and I don’t know how to modify it to change the text colour or button background:

```
runOnUiThread {

  alert {
      title = "My title"
      message = "My message"
      isCancelable = false
      positiveButton(android.R.string.ok) {
        // do something
      }
      negativeButton(android.R.string.cancel) {
        // do something else
      )
    }
  }.show()
}
```

I have spent all morning searching and trying out solutions (including the ones the SO suggest, as I type in my question) but I am just can’t get anything to work. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Garrett

Comment: Did you check: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I just restructured the code similar to so many of the examples online.

For the alert:

```
runOnUiThread {
  val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom)
  builder.setMessage("My message")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
       DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
       // do something
      })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
        // do something else
      })
    .setTitle("My title")
  val alertDialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
  // Set other dialog properties
  alertDialog.setCancelable(false)
  alertDialog.show()
}
```

And the styling to look after colr etc.:

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  <item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingBottom">2dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
  <item name="android:background">@color/colorWhite</item>
  <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorYellow</item>
</style>
```